# Prestashop I can't make regex_replace works

Tags: regex, prestashop, smarty

I have this regex_replace in my template :

```
{$product.unit_price_full|regex_replace:"/^[\d\s]*,?\d{2}\s*[€$₪]*\s*/u":""}
```

the `$product.unit_price_full` returns me "1,12 $ L" and my regex_replace `"/^[\d\s]*,?\d{2}\s*[€$₪]*\s*/" : " "` is supposed to remove everything before the "L" but it still display everything like the regex didn't worked, but I try it on regex101 it works perfectly.

If I add the unicode markup, it just removes the dollar symbol but nothing else

This is the output I get
`1,00&nbsp; 2.21`

So I have to capture the space markup in my regex rule?

Comment: Try `/^[\d\s]*,?\d{2}\s*[€$₪]*\s*/u`

Comment: that just removes the $ symbol and nothing else. (I have been read the article you just marked for duplicated, I posted this one because it was not the solution apparently :( please remove the flag if you're ok)

Comment: Are you sure it is at the string start? Try removing `^`. Also, try single quotes, `'/^[\d\s]*,?\d{2}\s*[€$₪]*\s*/u'`

Comment: I just tried, still everything display but the dollar symbol, for instance I edit my post to show the output I get

Comment: I just saw that I have an `&nbsp;` in my output :\ so I guess I found where the problem was, should I answer myself or not? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: If that space is actually a literal hard space, `\s` with `u` modifier must match it. Do you encode the string before passing to regex? You should not.

Comment: Ok! My first regex worked with your suggestion of adding single quotes instead of doubles o_o put that as answer so I mark your answer as solution. Thanks alot

Comment: Yes, I removed that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following changes:

- `$` inside a double quoted string literal is used to interpolate string literals and should be escaped with a single backslash if you need to make it a literal `$` char. Else, and it is recommended, just use single quotes
- As you have Unicode chars out of ASCII range in the pattern pass `u` modifier to the regex so that the string pattern and the input string could be correctly parsed with PCRE.

Use

```
{$product.unit_price_full|regex_replace:'/^[\d\s]*,?\d{2}\s*[€$₪]*\s*/u':""}
```